# When I use Cucumber (Scenario scenario) parameter in step def method,error displayed declared with 1 parameters. the gherkin step has 0 arguments

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I wrote the following feature step to take screen shot after failed scenario and close the browser. On the Step Defs method when I use (Scenario scenario) parameter  and Run it But it generates an error message.

Following Feature Step I wrote:

```
 And I close the browser
```

Following is the code I have written in Step Definition file for that step:

```
@And("^I close the broswer$")
public void i_Close_The_Broswer(Scenario scenario  ) throws Exception {
        if (scenario.isFailed()) {
        byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
        scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");

    }
```

Error Message displays after run:

```
 cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Arity mismatch: Step Definition 
'stepDefinations.LoginPageStepDefs.i_Close_The_Broswer(Scenario) in 
 file:/C:/Users/thaider/eclipse-workspace/AcWs_Automation/target/test- 
 classes/' with pattern [^I close the broswer$] is declared with 1 
 parameters. However, the gherkin step has 0 arguments [].
```

Test Base Class:

```
package utilities;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import cucumber.api.Scenario;
import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;

public class TestBase {

public static WebDriver driver;
public static Properties prop;


public TestBase() {
    try {
        prop = new Properties();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(
                "C:/Users/thaider/eclipse-workspace/AcWs_Automation/src/test/java/config/config.properties");
        prop.load(fis);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }


}


public static void initialization() {
    String browserName = prop.getProperty("browser");


if(browserName.equals("chrome")){
    //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/main/resources/Driver/chromedriver.exe");

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", prop.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver"));
   // System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile", prop.getProperty("log4j2ConfigFile"));
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
}

driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(TestUtil.PAGE_LOAD_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(TestUtil.IMPLICIT_WAIT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));


}
public static void closeSession() {
driver.quit();
}
}
```

Login Page Step Definition File:

```
package stepDefinations;

import java.awt.Window;
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException;
import cucumber.api.PendingException;
import cucumber.api.Scenario;
import cucumber.api.java.en.And;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
import pageObject_OR.AcceptContinue;
import pageObject_OR.LoginPage;
import utilities.TestBase;
import utilities.WindowsHandle;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class LoginPageStepDefs extends TestBase {
AcceptContinue acceptPage;
LoginPage loginPage;
WindowsHandle windowHandle;

@Given("^I want to open a browser$")
public void i_want_to_open_a_browser() throws Exception{
TestBase.initialization();



}



@Then("^I click on Accept & Continue$")
public void i_click_on_Accept_Continue() throws Exception{
    acceptPage = new AcceptContinue();
    acceptPage.clickAcceptContinue();
}


@Then("^I validate seal logo is displayed$")
public void i_validate_seal_logo_is_displayed() throws Exception {
    loginPage = new LoginPage();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    loginPage.validateCrmImage();


}




@Then("^I am in the ACWS login page as a CS User$")
public void i_am_in_the_ACWS_login_page_as_a_CS_User() throws Exception {
// Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
loginPage = new LoginPage();
loginPage.loginToHomePage("Testcs", "test123");
}



@And("^I close the broswer$")
public void i_Close_The_Broswer(Scenario scenario  ) throws Exception {
if (scenario.isFailed()) {
byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) 
driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");

}


TestBase.closeSession();
}
```

pom.xml File:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>AcWs_Automation</groupId>
<artifactId>AcWs_Automation</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<!-- REPORTING DEPENDENCIES ARE BELOW -->
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true </testFailureIgnore>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>3.15.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>execution</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <projectName>ExecuteAutomation</projectName>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-report-html</outputDirectory>
                        <cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>



<!-- Project Selenium, Junit, Apache POI Dependecy Below -->

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version> 3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.commons.io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>





    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>




    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.16-beta2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>openxml4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-beta</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core 
        <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId> <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId> 
        <version>2.11.2</version> </dependency> -->



    <!-- BELOW DEPENDECIES HAS BEEN COMMENTED OUT FOR DUPLIATION -->
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId> <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId> 
        <version>3.9</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId> 
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId> <version>3.9</version> </dependency> 
        <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId> <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId> 
        <version>3.9</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId> 
        <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId> <version>1.1</version> </dependency> 
        <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId> <artifactId>openxml4j</artifactId> 
        <version>1.0-beta</version> </dependency> -->

</dependencies>
```

Project Structure and Feature File

[image: Project Structure and Feature File]

Answer (score 2):

From the Cucumber API for Scenario (https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/core/src/main/java/cucumber/api/Scenario.java) :

> Before or After Hooks that declare a parameter of this type will receive an instance of this class

Note that it says only the Before and After hooks - not the Step definitions @And, @Given, @When, @Then.  Those expect **only** the arguments specified in the line expression.

Comment: Thank you, I have added created a class under my unility package name "Hooks.java" and added the Before and After annotation.  It seems to work.  Only issue now I am  having, If I run all the (mulitiple) feature files, my first feature file browser lunches and works fine but for the second feature files, instead of browser opening I get an Null Pointer Exception.  Could be due to the browser instance, Any idea how can I resolve this.  Again Thanks for your help.

Comment: @HaiderT That sounds like a coding bug - eg, you close the webdriver and set it to null, but don't create a new instance for the second feature.  Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example ( https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ) - so just empty steps, etc - and post it as a new question.