# How do print in Cluecumber report, even when test passes?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, cucumber

Generally, it it is seen that when the last assertfails, then the message gets into the cluecumber report
for eg.

```
assertFalse("Failed because of so and so reasons", true);
```

[image]

How do I still get something to get printed in the cluecumber report on passing?  Now, it comes like below
[image]

Comment: try using scenario.write(".....") or scenario.log("...") - depends on the version u r using

Comment: Thank you @Grasshopper. I am using 2.2.0 of cluecumber

Comment: @Grasshopper, any idea as how do I get inline as part of Steps in the report as the last step?

The below worked.  However it ended up coming as part of scenario hooks instead.



    `@After("@After")

    public void after(Scenario scenario) {

        scenario.write("Doest this work?");
  `

Comment: Place the log statement in the step definition

Comment: Thank you @Grasshopper.  I tried, but it failed as stated in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54876696/when-i-use-cucumber-scenario-scenario-parameter-in-step-def-method-error-displ.

Looks like apparently its not possible as per it.  Do you any working code snippet?

Thank you

Comment: In the before hook, store the scenario in a instance variable. Use that variable in the step definition method